# Best practise for creating database objects from .csv file

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

My situation is: having .csv file with some columns e.g. `name, surname, age, activity, and others` I want to create objects in my `relational` database with `row` from this file being single object. Column names correspond to model fields and with `others` being multiple columns defined by user who creates .csv (those `others` land in model's filed `comment` separated with commas). Having relational db, base on `model_1's` object I create `model_2` and `model_3`, all with the info from this .csv file.

My project is based on `django rest framework` and `react`.

Up till now my solution for this was to analize .csv file on with react using `FileReader` and `readAsArrayBuffer` which did it's job most of the time.

With `react` I not only have to analyze the file, but for every row make at least 3 x POSTing with axios. Sequentional posting is not ideal all the time.

My question is: > should files be analyzed on front- or back-end side ?

Heaving it done on the backend side with `python` seems a lot easier, but there might be a better solution of which I can't think of.

> EDIT:
> The database I use is `postgresql`.

Csv file size could go up to a 6000 rows. With this many rows I could just completely ram up on posts from react. Also making a single post with file to handle the work to django could also result in a overtime for response from server.

> EDIT2:

Example .csv file, might be a 6k rows long or more.

```
name,surname,activity,comment,Add_1,Add_2
franko1,romano2,asd1,smth1,1,2
franko2,romano3,asd2,smth2,2,3
franko3,romano4,asd3,smth3,3,4
franko4,romano5,asd4,smth4,4,5
franko5,romano6,asd5,smth5,5,6
franko6,romano7,asd6,smth6,6,7
franko7,romano8,asd7,smth7,7,8
franko8,romano9,asd8,smth8,8,9
franko9,romano10,asd9,smth9,9,10
```

Example models:

```py
class Users(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    surname = models.CharField()

class Clients(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Users)
    activity = models.CharField()

class Returns(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Clients)
    comment = models.CharField() <-- Add_1, Add_2 appended here
```

These models and .csv file are made up, as I am not allowed to provide those right ones, but dependencies between them are similar.

Users to Clients is OneToOne, Returns to Clients is ManyToOne relation.
My .csv contain a info to make all of those models sequentially: Users, Clients and Returns. Unfortunetally I'm not able to cut it down even to two models.

I have found a great node package for .csv files loadup - **papaparse**, opensource, great documentation and unbelivable functionality!

With this package I end up with already `.json` format for my upload.

Comment: what kind of db you use?

Comment: @JuConte postrgresql

Comment: can you provide a sample of the csv and models?

Comment: @yovelcohen hi! Checkout my second edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use pandas, as it's easiest to deal with CSV files quickly

```py
import pandas as pd
from my_app.models import Users,Clients,Returns

def convert_csv_to_models(csv_abs_path):
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_abs_path)
    df['users'] = df.apply(lambda row: Users(name=row['name'], surname=row['surname']), axis=1) # axis = 1 means the apply will run per row and per columns
    df['clients'] = df.apply(lambda row: Clients(user=row['users'], activity=row['activity']), axis=1)
    df['returns'] = df.apply(
        lambda row: Returns(client=row['clients'], comment=f'{row.comment} {row.Add_1} {row.Add_2}'), axis=1)

    cols_to_models = {'users': Users, 'clients': Clients, 'returns': Returns}
    for model, col in cols_to_models.items():
        # convert the column of objs to a list and then bulk create it
        objs = df[col].tolist()
        # ignore conflicts will ignore skip an object if it already exist
        model.objects.bulk_create(objs, ignore_conflicts=True)
```

I didn't quite understand what You wanted to achieve with the Returns and comments column, so I joined the comment, Add_1, and Add_2 columns to one string as the comment, you can modify as you need.

Also, it's not common practice to call Django Models in plural, you should do:

```py
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    surname = models.CharField()

class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Users)
    activity = models.CharField()

class Return(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Clients)
    comment = models.CharField()
```